# Nested select: insert values into table with two subqueries

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm developing a Stored procedure for SQL Server 2016.

I have to do this (the following sql statement doesn't work):

```
Insert into AggregationChildren (AggregationId, AggregationChildrenId, Position)
SELECT Parent, Serial, Position
FROM
    OPENJSON (@json, '$.Aggregations')
    WITH (  Parent nvarchar(20) '$.Parent',
            Children nvarchar(max) AS JSON )
        CROSS APPLY 
            OPENJSON (Children)
            WITH ( Serial nvarchar(20), Position int)
```

My problem is that `AggregationId` and `AggregationChildrenId` are integers and `Parent` and `Serial` are `nvarchar(20)`.

There is a relationship between `Parent` and `AggregationId`, and between `Serial` and `AggregationChildrenId`. I can get it using `Code` table.

I know how can I do it when I have to insert values for one column:

```
Insert into AggregationChildren (AggregationId)
    Select CodeId from Code Where Serial = (SELECT Parent
    FROM
        OPENJSON (@json, '$.Aggregations')
        WITH (  Parent nvarchar(20) '$.Parent',
                Children nvarchar(max) AS JSON )
            CROSS APPLY 
                OPENJSON (Children)
                WITH ( Serial nvarchar(20), Position int))
```

The data I'm trying to insert is:

```
{
    ...,
    "Aggregations": [{
        "Parent": "88962730000000004051",
        "Children": [{
            "Serial": "81861400000000020227",
            "Position": "1"
        }, {
            "Serial": "81861400000000033191",
            "Position": "2"
        }, {
            "Serial": "81861400000000046051",
            "Position": "3"
        },
        ...
        ]
    }, {
        "Parent": "88962730000000016653",
        "Children": [{
            "Serial": "81861400000001825849",
            "Position": "1"
        }, {
            "Serial": "81861400000001832643",
            "Position": "2"
        }, {
            "Serial": "81861400000001841911",
            "Position": "3"
        }, {
            "Serial": "81861400000001850803",
            "Position": "4"
        }, {
            "Serial": "81861400000001862474",
            "Position": "5"
        }, {
            "Serial": "81861400000001874774",
            "Position": "6"
        }, {
            "Serial": "81861400000001884159",
            "Position": "7"
        }, {
            "Serial": "81861400000001898352",
            "Position": "8"
        }, {
            "Serial": "81861400000001904764",
            "Position": "9"
        },
        ...
        ]
    }]
}
```

But, how can I do it if I have to use two `Select CodeId from Code Where Serial = (SELECT ...`?

I think I have to do something like this but without doing the same select three times:

```
 Insert into AggregationChildren (AggregationId, AggregationChildrenId, Position)
    Select CodeId from Code Where Serial = (SELECT Parent
    FROM
        OPENJSON (@json, '$.Aggregations')
        WITH (  Parent nvarchar(20) '$.Parent',
                Children nvarchar(max) AS JSON )
            CROSS APPLY
                OPENJSON (Children)
                WITH ( Serial nvarchar(20), Position int)), 
    Select CodeId from Code Where Serial = (SELECT Serial
    FROM
        OPENJSON (@json, '$.Aggregations')
        WITH (  Parent nvarchar(20) '$.Parent',
                Children nvarchar(max) AS JSON )
            CROSS APPLY
                OPENJSON (Children)
                WITH ( Serial nvarchar(20), Position int)), 
    SELECT Position
    FROM
        OPENJSON (@json, '$.Aggregations')
        WITH (  Parent nvarchar(20) '$.Parent',
                Children nvarchar(max) AS JSON )
            CROSS APPLY
                OPENJSON (Children)
                WITH ( Serial nvarchar(20), Position int)
```

Comment: Could you add some sample data?

Comment: @McNets I think the problem is with the select. I have to 'convert' `Parent` to CodeId and Serial to `CodeId` without the need to do the same select three times.

Comment: @McNets Sample data added but I don't think is going to be useful for the question about the selects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood correctly:

> ```
> create table AggregationChildren(AggregationId int, AggregationChildrenId int, Position int);
> create table Code (CodeID int, Serial nvarchar(20));
> insert into Code values
> (1, '88962730000000004051'),
> (2, '81861400000000020227'),
> (3, '81861400000000033191'),
> (4, '81861400000000046051'),
> (5, '88962730000000016653'),
> (6, '81861400000001825849'),
> (7, '81861400000001832643'),
> (8, '81861400000001841911'),
> (9, '81861400000001850803'),
> (10, '81861400000001862474'),
> (11, '81861400000001874774'),
> (12, '81861400000001884159'),
> (13, '81861400000001898352'),
> (14, '81861400000001904764');
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 14 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> declare @json nvarchar(max);
> set @json = '
> {
>     "Aggregations": [{
>         "Parent": "88962730000000004051",
>         "Children": [{
>             "Serial": "81861400000000020227",
>             "Position": "1"
>         }, {
>             "Serial": "81861400000000033191",
>             "Position": "2"
>         }, {
>             "Serial": "81861400000000046051",
>             "Position": "3"
>         }
>         ]
>     }, {
>         "Parent": "88962730000000016653",
>         "Children": [{
>             "Serial": "81861400000001825849",
>             "Position": "1"
>         }, {
>             "Serial": "81861400000001832643",
>             "Position": "2"
>         }, {
>             "Serial": "81861400000001841911",
>             "Position": "3"
>         }, {
>             "Serial": "81861400000001850803",
>             "Position": "4"
>         }, {
>             "Serial": "81861400000001862474",
>             "Position": "5"
>         }, {
>             "Serial": "81861400000001874774",
>             "Position": "6"
>         }, {
>             "Serial": "81861400000001884159",
>             "Position": "7"
>         }, {
>             "Serial": "81861400000001898352",
>             "Position": "8"
>         }, {
>             "Serial": "81861400000001904764",
>             "Position": "9"
>         }
>         ]
>     }]
> }
> ';
> ```

```
>     -- extract json fields
>     ;with x as 
>     (
>     SELECT 
>         Parent, 
>         Serial, 
>         Position
>     FROM
>         OPENJSON (@json, '$.Aggregations')
>         WITH (Parent nvarchar(20) '$.Parent', Children nvarchar(max) AS JSON)
>     CROSS APPLY 
>         OPENJSON (Children)
>         WITH (Serial nvarchar(20), Position int)
>     )
>     INSERT INTO AggregationChildren (AggregationId, AggregationChildrenId, Position)
>     SELECT c1.CodeID, c2.CodeID, Position
>     FROM   x
>     JOIN   Code c1
>     ON     c1.Serial = x.Parent
>     JOIN   Code c2
>     ON     c2.Serial = x.Serial;
>     GO
> 
12 rows affected
>
```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM AggregationChildren;
> GO
> ```
>
> AggregationId | AggregationChildrenId | Position
> ------------: | --------------------: | -------:
>             1 |                     2 |        1
>             1 |                     3 |        2
>             1 |                     4 |        3
>             5 |                     6 |        1
>             5 |                     7 |        2
>             5 |                     8 |        3
>             5 |                     9 |        4
>             5 |                    10 |        5
>             5 |                    11 |        6
>             5 |                    12 |        7
>             5 |                    13 |        8
>             5 |                    14 |        9

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8cb40415a623fc2f916124f44a232903)*